Pytorch Conv2d outputs infinity
My input x is a [1,256,60,120] shaped tensor. My Conv2d is defined as follows
import torch.nn as nn
conv2d = nn.Conv2d(
            256,
            256,
            kernel_size=2,
            stride=2,
            bias=False,
        ),

Some instances I see that conv2d(x).isinf().any() is True. Note that
x.max() = tensor(5140., device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16).
x.min() = tensor(0., device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16),
conv2d.weight.max() =tensor(1.5796, device='cuda:0')
conv2d.weight.min() = tensor(-0.8045, device='cuda:0')
Why do  I get infinity?

It is probably because you are using the half-precision float type for x, maybe there's a bit overflow

This is a case of numerical overflow.
Consider:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# set seed
torch.manual_seed(42)

# random values between 0 and 5140, like your values
x = (torch.rand(1, 256, 60, 120) * 5140)

# create conv layer
conv2d = nn.Conv2d(
            256,
            256,
            kernel_size=2,
            stride=2,
            bias=False,
        )

# set conv weights to a similar range to your values
torch.nn.init.uniform_(conv2d.weight, a=-0.8, b=1.57)

# compute output
y = conv2d(x)

print(y.max())
> tensor(1334073.6250, grad_fn=<MaxBackward1>)

When I run the code above, I see a max output value of 1334073.6250. You are using fp16 values, which overflow at 32000. You're seeing inf values because your output values exceed the range of fp16.
You should preprocess your inputs to have a more reasonable numeric range. Neural networks are very sensitive to numerical scale. Typically you want your input values to be roughly mean 0, variance 1. A max input value of 5140 is huge and likely to cause numeric issues in any situation.

Yes, this was correct. casting to torch.float32 worked for me. It was not a straight forward solution in my case because I was running in autocast, (torch.is_autocast_enabled() = True). So even if I converted manually the model and inputs to torch.float32, the output was still float16. Which is weird as intuitively I would assume that the autocast environment would figure out to use torch.float32 in this case.
Anyway, thank you so much!
